# Como mapear @ManyToMany com atributos extras em JPA com SpringBoot

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

Tenho um relacionamento **`Product`** ⎯⎯⎯⎯◆ **`Item`** ⎯⎯⎯◆ **`ShoppingCart`** e criei um mapeamento **`@ManyToMany`** entre `Product` e `ShoppingCart`, e, `Item` como tabela resultante desse relacionamento, de acordo com a UML na imagem abaixo. Mas apesar da tabela está sendo gerada corretamente, e os dados estarem sendo gravados, não consigo retornar o JSON de ShoppingCart. Como posso fazer esse mapeamento (**ManyToMany c/ dados extras**) da forma correta?
Seguem a UML do projeto, o print do erro, e o link do projeto no GitHub (veja a brach **temp/tony**):

- **Link do Projeto**: [image: Github Badge]
- **UML**:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Erro**:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Product**:

```java
package com.supera.games.domain.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  public String image;
  private String name;
  private BigDecimal price;
  private Integer score;

  @Transient
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.product")
  private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<>();

  public Product() {
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getImage() {
    return image;
  }

  public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public BigDecimal getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  public Integer getScore() {
    return score;
  }

  public void setScore(Integer score) {
    this.score = score;
  }

  // pega a lista de carrinhos onde o produto participou
  @Transient
  public Set<ShoppingCart> getCarts() {
    Set<ShoppingCart> carts = new HashSet<>();
    for (Item item : items) {
      carts.add(item.getCart());
    }

    return carts;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Product product = (Product) o;
    return id.equals(product.id);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id);
  }
}
```

**Item**:

```java
package com.supera.games.domain.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.supera.games.domain.model.pk.CartItemPK;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_cart_item")
public class Item implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @EmbeddedId
  private final CartItemPK id = new CartItemPK();

  private Integer quantity;
  private BigDecimal shipping;
  private BigDecimal price;

  public Item() {
  }

  //  public Item(ShoppingCart cart, Product product, Integer quantity, BigDecimal price) {
  public Item(ShoppingCart cart, Product product, Integer quantity) {
    id.setCart(cart);
    id.setProduct(product);

    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.shipping = new BigDecimal("10.00");
    this.price = product.getPrice();
  }

  public Integer getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
  }

  public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }

  public BigDecimal getShipping() {
    return shipping;
  }

  public void setShipping(BigDecimal shipping) {
    this.shipping = shipping;
  }

  public BigDecimal getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  @JsonIgnore
  public ShoppingCart getCart() {
    return id.getCart();
  }

  public void setCart(ShoppingCart cart) {
    id.setCart(cart);
  }

  public Product getProduct() {
    return id.getProduct();
  }

  public void setProduct(Product product) {
    id.setProduct(product);
  }


  @Transactional
  public BigDecimal getTotalValue() {
    BigDecimal qnt = BigDecimal.valueOf(quantity);
    return qnt.multiply(price);
  }


  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Item item = (Item) o;
    return id.equals(item.id);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id);
  }
}
```

**ShoppingCart:**

```java
package com.supera.games.domain.model;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;


@Entity
public class ShoppingCart {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  private OffsetDateTime createdAt;

//  @Transient
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.cart", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<>();

  public ShoppingCart() {
  }

  public ShoppingCart(OffsetDateTime createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public OffsetDateTime getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
  }

  public void setCreatedAt(OffsetDateTime createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
  }

  public Set<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
  }

  public void setItems(Set<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
  }

  @Transactional
  public BigDecimal subtotal() {
    return null;
  }

  @Transactional
  public BigDecimal total() {
    return null;
  }

  @Transactional
  public BigDecimal totalShipping() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart) o;
    return id.equals(cart.id) && createdAt.equals(cart.createdAt);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, createdAt);
  }
}
```

**Item PK:**

```java
package com.supera.games.domain.model.pk;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import com.supera.games.domain.model.Product;
import com.supera.games.domain.model.ShoppingCart;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
public class CartItemPK implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
  private ShoppingCart cart;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
  private Product product;

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    CartItemPK carItemPK = (CartItemPK) o;
    return cart.equals(carItemPK.cart) && product.equals(carItemPK.product);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(cart, product);
  }
}
```

E testei o mapeamento salvando e recuperando com algo assim:
**CartService:**

```java
public ShoppingCart saveItem(Item item) {

  Optional<Product> product = productRepository.findById(item.getProduct().getId());
  ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart(OffsetDateTime.now());

  ShoppingCart ct = cartRepository.save(cart);
  Item it = new Item(ct, product.get(), item.getQuantity());
  Item i = itemRepository.save(it);

  ct.getItems().add(i);
  ShoppingCart obj = cartRepository.save(ct);
  return obj;
}

 
public List<ShoppingCart> getAllCarts() {
  // get all carts
  List<ShoppingCart> carts = cartRepository.findAll();
  return carts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O atributo 'items' está com FetchType.LAZY, isso significa que quando você busca no banco usando o `cartRepository.findAll()`, os objetos associados a ele não são recuperados. Quando você tenta transformar para JSON vai lançar aquele `failed to lazily initialize`.

```java
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.cart", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<>();
```

Uma opção seria usar FetchType.EAGER

Comment: Já tentei usar o EAGER, mas ainda continua ocorrendo o mesmo problema! :(. Você olhou as classes apenas aqui ou chegou a ver as branches desse projeto no GitHub?

Comment: @TonySilva após usar o EAGER tente usar @JsonIgnore no atributo `private ShoppingCart cart;` da classe `CartItemPK` e no `private Set<Item> items` da classe `Product`. Provavelmente está ocorrendo uma referência circular, onde o ShoppingCart precisa mostrar os itens e os itens precisam mostrar o ShoppingCart, e a mesma coisa irá acontecer no Product. O @JsonIgnore não vai deixar serializar o atributo que você marcar com essa anotação

Comment: [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations) dê uma olhada nesse link